# Error starting a Next.js application in https

Tags: node.js, https, next.js

I'm attempting to start a Next.js application in https mode. I'm following the instructions [here](https://medium.com/responsetap-engineering/nextjs-https-for-a-local-dev-server-98bb441eabd7). When I try to open the page, I get the following error:

> TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

here's my code:

```html
const { createServer } = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const {next} = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();


//read the .env file
dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT;

const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./certificates/privateKey.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificates/certificate.crt"),
};
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Server started on https://localhost:" + port);
  });

});
```

Here's the stack trace:

```html
TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function
    at IBOUIApp (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\.next\server\pages\_app.js:53:92)
    at d (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at exports.renderToString (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\.next\server\vendors-node_modules_next_dist_pages__document_js.js:627:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:1145)
    at async C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:112:97
    at async C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:105:142
    at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:137:387)
    at async DevServer.renderToHTML (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:138:610)
    at async DevServer.renderToHTML (C:\Users\mgardner\workspace\qa-tool-backoffice\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js:36:578)
```

Comment: did you find a solution

Comment: actually i fixed the issue by starting my application with `export NODE_ENV=dev node server.js` command

Comment: Use ngrok, very easy to use tool to make local port available online via https. Method explained here: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/run-next-js-app-locally-in-https/